# Delegating whole class bad practice?

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented, c++

Suppose I have the following struct:

```
struct Dimension
{
    void setDimension(Vector2i dim);
    Vector2i getDimension() const;
    bool canShowInformation();
}
```

And this struct uses the Dimension struct:

```
struct ApplicationState
{
    Dimension dim;
    State currentState;

    //Delegate everything to Dimension struct.
    void setDimension(Vector2i dim)
    {
        dim.setDimension(dim);
    }
    Vector2i getDimension() const
    {
        return dim.getDimension();
    }
    bool canShowInformation()
    {
        return canShowInformation();
    }
}
```

Is it bad to wrap almost all methods of `Dimension` struct in the `ApplicationState` struct?  I do this so that I won't have long method calls like this:

```
appState.dim.setDimension(...)
//or
appState->dim.setDimension(...)
```

Is there a design principle or pattern which solves this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're delegating _everything_, why not just inherit?

Comment: @PhilipKendall ApplicationState will have other functionality not related to the dimension, like stuff related to the currentState and StateChanges.  So it won't just be a special case of ```Dimension```. If for example ```ÀpplicationState``` will have 10 methods at the end and only three of them are delegations to ```Dimension``` should I inherit from ````Dimension```?

Comment: "so that I want have long method" do you mean won't?

Comment: long method names are considered a good thing(tm)

Comment: @Ewan yup, used wrong word, thanks

Comment: @Ewan, but that isn't really about a long method name, but more about a chain of function/method calls. thisFunctionDoesThis() vs object1->object2()->thisFunctionDoesThis().

Comment: what is it that you dont like about the nested object?

Comment: @Ewan, mostly, calls like this take up too much space, and a less convenient to read.

Comment: so.. it _is_ the length rather than the nesting? ie a.dim1Method() is just as bad as a.dim.method() ? I think you are going against modern "best practice" which suggests that longer, more natural language sounding names are best ie application.Dimension.CanShowInformation is better than a.dim.showInfo

Comment: @Ewan of course, you are right, application.Dimension.CanShowInformation is better than a.dim.showInfo, but this is not the point of my question. I choose bad naming with my ````dim``` variable, but lets suppose I name everything according to best practices, with your example it would be ```application.Dimension.CanShowInformation```. My question was, whether or not it is a sign of bad design to go through two or more objects to call a function or access a variable.

Comment: In addition to what Christophe said below, if AppState is a thing that conceptually *has* a dimension instance as its part, then doing this wrapping for ease of use (at the cost of more dificult maintenance) kind of undoes what you've accomplished by defining the Dimension struct in the first place. You've created a separate struct that represents the "dimension" concept in a higher level way - and now you're polluting your AppState class with details that are the responsibility of Dimension. You can always create a local ref/ptr to 'appState.dim', & then just do `dim.setDimension(...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on your design intention:

- If `ApplicationState` and `Dimension` address [different concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/) and may evolve due to different reasons, then it is fine.
- Likewise, if `ApplicationState` is just there for using a `Dimension` with another interface/protocol, then it is an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) and is also fine.
- If `ApplicationState` is nothing else than a specialized `Dimension`, then this might be overkill.

To make up your design decision, you should also be aware that lots of `appState.dim.dimOperation()` creates a de facto coupling that works well in practice but makes the code difficult to maintain (see also [principle of least knowledge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)).